# How to change the displayed Value to one of the available options in a dijit.form.ComboBox?

Tags: combobox, dojo

I have a dijit.form.ComboBox defined declaratively:

```
<select dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="mycb">
  <option value="A">Alpha</option>
  <option value="B">Beta</option>
  <option value="C">Charlie</option>
</select>
```

When using

```
dijit.byId("mycb").set("value","B");
```

the displayed Content changes to "B" and not to "Beta".

What am I doing wrong handling the ComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was using a "dijit.form.ComboBox" in place of a  Element.

A dijit.form.ComboBox behaves like a html  element wich gives a number of options to choose from.

The element that corresponds to a  is "dijit.form.FilteringSelect". Using this dijit, the above method will work.